# JQuery autocomplete how to write label in autocomplete text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hello I am using jQuery UI autocomplete.

I am getting values and labels from the drop down area. I will write the value in a hidden input and use it later. I could do that, but I cannot write the label in the search input, after the select item. When I select a row in the dropdown box, the value of the row is displayed in the search area (#tags), but I want the label in there.

Here is my code:
Thanks

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var selectedLabel = null;
            var yerler = [
                { "value": 3, "label": "Adana Seyhan" }, 
                { "value": 78, "label": "Seyhan Adana" },
                { "value": 17, "label": "Paris Fransa" }, 
                { "value": 123, "label": "Tokyo Japan"}
            ];

            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: yerler,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#projeKatmanRaporCbx").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });    
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
            <input id="tags" />
            <input type="text" id="projeKatmanRaporCbx" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a `return false` (or `event.preventDefault`) in the `select` event solves half of your problem. The remaining problem can be solved by adding a `focus` event:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: yerler,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#projeKatmanRaporCbx").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/VvETA/1/)

Comment: how do i make tag names as text input and need to store those names in external file like `.txt` eg:i have a input box it allows user to type their country, Since i have list of country in text file, So when user starts typing `AM` `jQuery` should load all words from text file that matches `AM` in first two letter

Comment: I think you could: load the file via AJAX, convert the content to an array (`content.split(/\r\n/)`), set this array as source.

Comment: event.preventDefault() is the key. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Add a return false; after setting the labels.

```
var selectedLabel = null;
      var yerler = [
     { "value": 3, "label": "Adana Seyhan" }, 
     { "value": 78, "label": "Seyhan Adana" },
     { "value": 17, "label": "Paris Fransa" }, 
     { "value": 123, "label": "Tokyo Japan"}];

      $("#tags").autocomplete({
          source: yerler,
          select: function (event, ui) {

              $("#projeKatmanRaporCbx").val(ui.item.value);
              $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);

              return false;
          }
      });
```

Comment: It is working. but i couldn't able to create autocomplete after getting data from ajax

Answer (score 1):

just add return false to your function like this, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UEL27/1/)

```
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: yerler,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#projeKatmanRaporCbx").val(ui.item.value);
            $( "#tags" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is my code where i use desc from autocomplete to fill into next element that is an hidden input box :

Check if this helps you in something

```
function getTage() {
var availableTags = [
    {assign var=result_products_cnt value=1}
    {foreach from=$result_products item=product}
        {if $result_products_cnt eq $result_products_total}
            { label: "{$product.name}", value: "{$product.name}", desc: "{$product.id_product}" }
        {else}
            { label: "{$product.name}", value: "{$product.name}", desc: "{$product.id_product}" },
        {/if}
        {assign var=result_products_cnt value=$result_products_cnt+1}
    {/foreach}
];
return availableTags;
}
var availableTags = getTage();
$( "#nxpublisher_productid_"+i ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).next().val(ui.item.desc);
  },
  open: function() { $('.ui-menu').width(400); $('.ui-menu li a').css("font-weight", "bold"); $('.ui-menu li a').css("text-align", "left");}
});
```

nxpublisher_productid_ is one of the id of my multiple taxtboxes where i want to initiate autocomplete.

P.S i have used this function in smarty so please dont mind copying complete function.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny plugin for a general purpose solution:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.autocompleteHidden = function($hiddenInput, autocompleteOpts) {
        if ('string' == typeof $hiddenInput) {
            $hiddenInput = $($hiddenInput);
        }
        var $input = this;
        var opts = $.extend({}, autocompleteOpts, {
            focus: function(evt, ui) {
                $input.val(ui.item.label);
                if (autocompleteOpts.focus) {
                    autocompleteOpts.focus.apply(this, arguments);
                }
                return false;
            }
            , select: function(evt, ui) {
                $hiddenInput.val(ui.item.value);
                $input.val(ui.item.label);
                if (autocompleteOpts.select) {
                    autocompleteOpts.select.apply(this, arguments);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        this.autocomplete(opts);
        $input.change(function(evt) {
            if (/^\s*$/.test(this.value)) {
                $hiddenInput.val('');
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So where you'd use `yourInput.autocomplete(options)`, you instead use `yourInput.autocompleteHidden(selectorOrJqueryObject, options)`. This has the benefit of still allowing additional `focus` and `select` options, without repeated code. It also clears the hidden input when no (visible) value is entered in the main input.