# Linq select many into new column

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to make a jquery auto complete where I use a label and value [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312840/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-write-label-in-autocomplete-text-input) which means that I need my json in the form of

```
{ label: 'label text', value: 'value text' }
```

However I am filtering a list of Employees which is a class with the following structure:

```
public sealed class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PersonnelNumber { get; set; }
    public int RecID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

So I tried the following Linq to get the format of label, value I needed:

```
var jsonResult = employees
                  .SelectMany(emp => new { label = emp.Name, value = emp.RecID })
                  .ToList();
```

Where employees is a list of `Employee` objects but it is throwing up an build error of

> Error 1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How do I fix this to get the `Name` and `RecID` in a new list of objects with `label` and `value` as their output?

Comment: If you're going home - then I am too! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just want to use `Select` here:

```
var jsonResult = employees
    .Select(emp => new { label = emp.Name, value = emp.RecID })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was after.  My brain isn't back up to speed after the long easter weekend and thought `SelectMany` was for if you wanted more than one record!

Answer (score 5):

`SelectMany` is for "flattening" a group of collections.  Since you just have a single collection just use `Select`:

```
var jsonResult = employees.Select(emp => new { label = emp.Name, value = emp.RecID })
                          .ToList();
```